# javascript HTML jquery client-side freeform text search neocities.org

Tags: javascript

Recently I got a free account with the wonderful neocities.org.
They are one of the few free hosts that allow you to program your free site
in HTML/CSS/javascript/jQUERY.
No PHP
NO serverside programming.

So
I uploaded that one-megabyte freeform text file.
Why
I hope, I do not know how, to allow visitors of my site
to fill a simple form 
(a substring, a boolean bunch of words a la google, or
 - I know I am pushing it - a regular expression)

The answer returned should be
a window (or a frame)
that (after querying that freeform file I mentioned)
returning the LINES
that have the contents of that form.
Only those lines.
Well, may be with some highlighting of the search terms

a FILTER.

### Certainly I do not need sql, or php, or java or ...

Help

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. You can improve your question by providing some code to show what you’ve tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am still learnigng javascript.  So sorry I cannot provide code.

What I wanna do is search a certain unstructured text file (one megabyte) that
I will upload to my free account on neocities.org.

(actually I want any visitor to my site to do the searching)

Kinda like having my own little custom Google (with search extensions: substrings, Booleans, regular expressions).

Any visitor to my site should be able to fill a simple form (e.g Great Britain)
and get rewarded with a listing of all the lines of my text file that contain
the query term (e.g Great Britain). But none of the lines that do NOT mention 
the query term.

A filter.

Extra marks for highlighting/colorizing the query terms (e.g Great Britain).

Hope I have made my specs a bit clearer, now.

Comment: The specs are a bit clearer, but if you need someone to code your project for you, then you should hire a developer  Stackoverflow exists to help you solve problems in code that you already wrote